# Pointcut expression returning throws error

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I have  defined a pointcut like this

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.personal.services.Example.buildList(..))")
public void contextInterceptor() {
//pointcut identifier
}
```

I want to use it for afterReturning advice. 
How do I add the returning  variable so that I can access it in my advice?

```
@AfterReturning("contextInterceptor()")
public Object contextAdvice(JoinPoint jp, Object returnObj){
//process returnobj;
return returnObj;
}
```

I tried this but it gives me error

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.personal.services.Example.buildList(..))",returning="returnObj")
```

Comment: What error does it give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in one method like this:

```java
@AfterReturning(
    pointcut = "execution(* com.personal.services.Example.buildList(..))",
    returning = "retVal"
)
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object retVal) {
    if (retObject != null) {
        logger.error("Returned object: " + retVal);
        logger.error("Returned type:   " + retVal.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I would still prefer to define the pointcut. This will help to  combine several pointcuts if needed later.

Comment: @MonaD: I think you should accept his answer anyway, the separate pointcut is just cosmetics. He answered your question. BillFromHawaii: I have fixed your code (wrong parameter name) and reformatted it a bit.

Comment: Sure.. This site has been a great help. Thanks for all the dedicated users who provide answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. 
I am doing this and its now working fine.

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="contextInterceptor()",returning="returnObj")
```